# How to set PyCharm Jupyter notebook URL?

Tags: pycharm

The first time I create and run an iPython notebook file I am required to enter the jupyter notebook URL with the authentication token as shown below.

[image]

The problem is, I accidentally pasted in the wrong link and am unable to connect to the jupyter notebook.

[image]

But when I press the 'Run Jupyter Notebook' option I get the following window and its not clear where I should set the URL and the authentication token.

[image]

Comment: It turns out that when you first use your jupyter NB, you will need to start Jupyter and you will get the URL like the following.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqQjK.jpg)